# Ineffective mark compact near heap limit allocation failed when "aot=true"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-build, angular-aot

I am trying to make a build of my angular application on 1vCPU and 1GB memory machine, ]it worked fine at start but as project is getting bigger, it fails with the error "Javascript heap out of memory"
But, when aot=false is set, it works fine.
Below is the complete detail -

At the start of the Angular, deployment with below command was working fine.

```
ng build
```

Then after new components started to add on, it started failing with "*Javascript heap out of memory*". So changed the 'scripts' > 'build' value in package json to -

```
"build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=prod"
```

It worked for sometime, but build start to fail again wth error -

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa1a640 node::Abort() [ng build --prod]
 2: 0xa1aa4c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [ng build --prod]
 3: 0xb9a62e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng build --prod]
 4: 0xb9a9a9 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng build --prod]
 5: 0xd57c25  [ng build --prod]
 6: 0xd582b6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [ng build --prod]
 7: 0xd64b75 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng build --prod]
 8: 0xd65a25 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng build --prod]
 9: 0xd684dc v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [ng build --prod]
10: 0xd2eefb v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [ng build --prod]
11: 0x10714ce v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng build --prod]
12: 0x140dc19  [ng build --prod]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So through multiple sites, I tried below command and it worked fine

```
ng build --aot=false
```

Server output -

```
Output :
Initial Chunk Files | Names         |      Size
vendor.js           | vendor        |   6.81 MB
main.js             | main          | 809.57 kB
styles.css          | styles        | 428.40 kB
polyfills.js        | polyfills     | 239.18 kB
scripts.js          | scripts       | 145.27 kB
runtime.js          | runtime       |   6.15 kB
```

But, I want the code to complied before, so setting aot=false should not be the permanent solution.
Can anyone help me with what I should do, to solve this issue permanently.

Below are the other specifications that I am working with
Angular/cli - 11.2.14
Typescript - 4.1.6

Angular.json file -

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    ...
    "aot": true,
    ...
  },
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true
    }
  }
}
```

Server specs:
vCPUs - 1
memory - 1GiB

Comment: Will lazy loading be helpful? or do I need to increase the server specifications?

Comment: Implemented lazy loading. So the deployment works fine with aot=true. But still gets killed when try to deploy with productionized build i.e. --prod

Comment: Finally increased the server specs to run the optimized build